# Column data format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a DB table FILE_TABLE the requirement is consolidate the file name and extension in one new column. The file extension can be anything. Which will be mentioned in MIMETYPE column. It can be application/pdf, image/tiff or audio/x-ms-wma etc.

```
FILE_TABLE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  MIMETYPE      DOC_NAME           TITLE            DOC_TITLE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1.  image/jpeg    abc_image          null             abc_image.jpeg
2.  image/jpeg    xyz_image.jpeg     null             xyz_image
3.  image/jpeg    lmn_image          lmn_image.jpeg   null
4.  image/jpeg    123_img            123_img          null
5.  image/jpeg    567_img            null             567_img
6.  image/jpeg    null               987_img          987_img
7.  image/jpeg    321_img            321_img          321_img
8   app/pdf       abc                null             abc
```

I will also have the MIMETYPE_TABLE lookup table for extension. Something like this.

```
MIMETYPE_TABLE 
-------------------------------
ID  MIMETYPE           FILE_EXT     
-------------------------------
1   application/json   json
2   image/jpeg         jpeg
3   application/pdf    pdf
4   audio/x-ms-wma     wma
```

The expected result should be qualified file name with extension in NEW_DOCNAME as shown below.

```
FILE_TABLE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  MIMETYPE    DOC_NAME        TITLE           DOC_TITLE       NEW_DOCNAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.  image/jpeg  abc_image       null            abc_image.jpeg  abc_image.jpeg
2.  image/jpeg  xyz_image.jpeg  null            xyz_image       xyz_image.jpeg
3.  image/jpeg  lmn_image       lmn_image.jpeg  null            lmn_image.jpeg
4.  image/jpeg  123_img         123_img         null            123_img.jpeg
5.  image/jpeg  567_img         null            567_img         567_img.jpeg
6.  image/jpeg  null            987_img         987_img         987_img.jpeg
7.  image/jpeg  321_img         321_img         321_img         321_img.jpeg
8   app/pdf     abc             null            abc             abc.pdf
```

Comment: You've told us your requirement, but not what you are stuck on - you haven't shown what you have tried or what was wrong with it.

Comment: Also how are you deriving the extension from the mime type, do you have a lookup, or are you just assuming the bit after the slash is right (which doesn't really work for WMA)? And what should happen if more than one of `doc_name`, `title` and `doc_title` are set, but different - can that happen? If so which takes precedence? And what if those values already have an extension and it doesn't match the mime type?

Comment: @Alex Poole I can create a mine type lookup table. I updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join your table with lookup table and generate the required value as following:

```
select f.*,
       coalesce(f.doc_name, f.title, f.doc_title) 
       || case when
          instr(coalesce(f.doc_name, f.title, f.doc_title), '.' || m.file_ext) = 0 
          then m.file_ext 
          end as new_docname
from file_table f 
join mimetype_table m
on (f.mimetype = m.mimetype)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table FILE_TABLE add NEW_DOCNAME varchar2(100);
update FILE_TABLE set NEW_DOCNAME = replace(coalesce(DOC_NAME,TITLE,DOC_TITLE),'.jpeg') || '.jpeg';
```